# Swap image/hyperlink based on pathname using Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, pathname

I know this is probably pretty simple but I am a novice at JavaScript.

Trying to change the image/link being displayed based on the url path.

So any page at foo.com would display an image of a dog `<div id="promo"><a href="dog.html"><img src="img/dog.jpg"></a></div>`

Unless it was under a the directory foo.com/cat then `<div id="promo"><a href="cat.html"><img src="img/cat.jpg"></a></div>`

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. What have you tried, what is not working?

Comment: `code`<script type="text/javascript"> 
          var loc = window.location.pathname; 
          loc =loc.toLowerCase(); 
          if(window.location.hostname != "foo.com"  &&  loc.indexOf("/cat")<0){ 



            } 
</script>`code`

Comment: this is the path i started down, but I just can't figure it out. Like i said I am a novice at javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can achieve this with the markup you posted:

```
<div id="promo">
  <a href="dog.html">
    <img src="img/dog.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Now here some vanilla JavaScript that does what you need: changes the image src based on the location pathname:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var promo = document.getElementById('promo');    

if(path.match(/cat/)){
  promo.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = 'img/cat.jpg';
}​
```

You can also view this with source with a test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/jordanandree/3yCgY/2/